# Where to put the php code in android?

Tags: php, android, xml

Or another way to parse an image from returned xml file?  I know this question will be getting a lot of negatives, but the thing is I am a noob at this networking thing. As foolish as this may sound, still I had to ask: where should I put the PHP code? I am developing an app which has to display the image of an artist as the background, and I came across this code:

```
<?php

$url    = 'http://api.discogs.com/artist/';
$artist = 'deadmau5';
$data   = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $artist));

$image  = $data->resp->artist->images[0]->uri;

?>
```

But I don't know where to put this code. If I put this code in the XML file wrapping it around the tag `<![CDATA[` will it work?

Comment: Is this a web app (viewed in the phone's browser), or a native app (written in Java)?

Comment: well its written in java.....i am building  music player and at some point i want the background to be the artist's image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read from this site, XMLparser and ImageLoader class
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you want just to show a network image or not.
1. Use native library like Volley to show image with NetworkImageView or ImageLoader. It is sim-offical library of Google.
2. You can not run PHP code directly. You've to run a webserver on your device and to make it run your PHP code. The server should be packaged into your APK and runs after the App being installed. I've not hear whether it could work. :)

Conclusion: do it with 1. to show your image from network.
More question to Volley?

The example from @Hà Link is correct, but it should be enhanced by volley's NetworkImageView. It could be better.

Comment: Yes....can you show some e.g  on Volley?or a link to an e.g? or any tutorial?

Comment: and will i be albe to parse image from an xml file?

Comment: well i had seen the link before ....there were a lot of  classes used...so that made me a bit confused

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava You should do follow thing. 1. Use Jackson to read your xml or other libraries which can do the same thing. 2. sImageLoader = new ImageLoader()//Volley; imageView.setImageUrl("image url", sImageLoader);

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all image urls from xml use library like FasterXml, Jackson. You could, of course use, Regex to fetch them.

sImageLoader = new ImageLoader(....); 
networkImageView.setImageUrl("image url", sImageLoader);

Comment: I am a noob at this networking thing,so please can you elaborate a little ?
see there is a site http://api.discogs.com/artist/name-of-artist

which returns an xml file containing the images....

1.first of all i don't know how to create a link with this website, to get the xml file...
2.After i get the xml file,what should i do?i am not asking for the code just guide me a little bit

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava To 2. After you got your xml file, you've to parser it with Android SDK or a library like FasterXML. To 1. I recommend still to use Volley to post with the URL http://api.discogs.com/artist/deadmau5 . There is a very mini-sample here to show how Volley posts a request. https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples/blob/master/src/com/github/volley_examples/Act_SimpleRequest.java

Comment: Well thanx ..this volley thing is a bit more complex..i think i will go with @Ha link's answer..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use PHP in a native Android application. Android does not have any sort of PHP parser or method of executing PHP scripts.

It looks like you are trying to get JSON, and use that JSON in your application. If this is the case, you will likely want to look into a library such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to help parse the JSON into Java objects.

However, it also sounds like you might be trying to complete this project as your very first Android project. If that is the case, I highly recommend you spend some time going through tutorials and creating simple projects to become familiar with the Android framework before trying to dive much further into a more complex project such as this.

Comment: well its not my first project but i guess i was misguided 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194273/fetching-specific-objects-say-image-from-a-webpageor-any-image-providing-serv

there are already api's for parsing images from sites like lastfm etc......so i guess i won't be needing the JSON thing...